# For each element in array add string into second array

Tags: javascript

For each element of the array arr[], i need to add this string to another array. I tried like this:

```js
var arr = ["TagID3", "TagID4", "TagID5", "TagID6", "TagID7", "TagID8", "TagID9"];
var newarr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  newarr.push({
    "id": i,
    "valueAxis": i,
    "bullet": "round",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": i
  })
}

for (var d = 0; d < newarr.length; d++) {
  document.write(newarr[d]);
}
```

But it show only **[object Object]**

Comment: Your new array looks fine, try `console.log` instead (don't use `document.write`. if you *do* need to print it as a string, then stringify first)

Comment: `document.write` cannot properly parse an enumerable, which is why it only shows [Object object]. It's the same as `alert()`. Either way, you're not supposed to use document.write.

Comment: or you can just use `document.write(JSON.stringify(newarr[d]));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, however you could use `JSON.stringify()` to write the result to your document that is readable. This would address the `[object Object]` issue you noted:

```js
var arr = ["TagID3", "TagID4", "TagID5", "TagID6", "TagID7", "TagID8", "TagID9"];
var newarr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  newarr.push({
    "id": i,
    "valueAxis": i,
    "bullet": "round",
    "type": "smoothedLine",
    "valueField": i
  })
}

/*  
for (var d = 0; d < newarr.length; d++) {

  // Use JSON.stringify to produce a string from JSON object
  // that will write to document in readable way
  var stringValue = JSON.stringify(newarr[d])

  document.write(stringValue);
}
*/

// Write item data from in newarr as comma separated, readable string
document.write(newarr.map(JSON.stringify).join());
```

Comment: can i have another question? How i can add comma between braces. It must be look like this {......},{.......}

Comment: @DacreDenny You're my hero. Thank you.